# azure function scaling with App Service Plan

Tags: azure-functions

How do I scale azure function when hosted as App Service Plan. The only option I see is Scale up. This seem to be no option to Scale out. I have not setup any web app only azure functions.

Answer (score 2):

It should be in Platform Features -> All settings, as shown below:

[image]